# What is the meaning of Void -> (Void) in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know the meaning of `(void)` in Objective-C but I want to know what is the meaning of this code in Swift:

```
(Void) -> (Void)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`() -> ()` just means `Void -> Void` - a closure that accepts no parameters and has no return value.

In Swift, Void is an typealias for an empty tuple, ().

`typealias Void = ()`
The empty tuple type.

This is the default return type of functions for which no explicit return type is specified.

For an example

```
let what1: Void->Void = {}
```

or

```
let what2: Int->Int = { i in return i }
```

are both valid expressions with different types. So print has the type `()->() (aka Void->Void)`. Strictly speaking, printThat has type `(() -> ()) -> () (aka (Void->Void)->Void`

**Void function** doesn't has a lot of sense as **Int function** etc ... Every function in Swift has a type, consisting of the function’s parameter types and return type.

Finally, regarding "void" functions, note that there is no difference between these two function signatures:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String)        // implicitly returns _value_ '()' of _type_ ()
func myFunc(myVar: String) -> ()
```

Curiously enough, you can have an optional empty tuple type, so the function below differs from the two above:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String) -> ()? {
    print(myVar)
    return nil
}

var c = myFunc("Hello") /* side effect: prints 'Hello'
                       value: nil
                       type of c: ()?              */
```

Comment: This is no longer accurate. If a function, method, or closure doesn't accept parameters, you communicate this to the compiler by using a pair of parentheses. You cannot use `Void` for this. In other words, `Void -> Void` is not valid Swift. I explain this in more detail here https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-void-in-swift.

Answer (score 1):

Void is a data type that is common across a lot of programming languages, in Swift’s standard library, it’s simply an empty tuple. It’s used for for functions that return nothing.

When defining a function, if you don’t specify a return type, you get a function that return Void; this is how it’s defined in the standard library:

```
public typealias Void = ()
```

You use Void to declare the type of a function, method, or closure...

Keep in mind that `()` can mean two things:

- `()` can be a type – the empty tuple type, which is the same as `Void`.
- `()` can be a value – an empty tuple, which is the same as `Void()`.

Answer (score -1):

Same meaning in Swift. No parameter no return value.